# software to compute the degree of the splitting field of a polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, math-software, splitting-field, computational-algebra

I want to do some experiments regarding the degree of the splitting field $\mathbb{Q}$ of a certain class of polynomials in $\mathbb{Q}[T]$. Is there some software that is able to compute the (degree of the) splitting field of a given such polynomial? Are there for example macaulay2 packages or is it implemented in mathematica, maple etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/) can do this. It's free. One can even try it out online.

An example from [their documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/splitting_field.html):

```
sage: R.<x> = PolynomialRing(QQ)  
sage: K.<a> = (x^3 + 2).splitting_field(); K  
Number Field in a with defining polynomial x^6 + 3*x^5 + 6*x^4 + 11*x^3 + 12*x^2 - 3*x + 1
```